# identifyImage() in Imagemagick resetting connection in PHP?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, identify

I've come across an odd problem with the following code:

```
$image = new Imagick($real_location); 
$ident = $image->identifyImage(); 
$format = $ident['colorSpace'];
```

In most cases, this is fine. But on some photos it resets the connection and basically makes it look like the page has timed out.

An example photo is a JPG at 72dpi, 3008x2000, EXIF data included, RGB, 8Bit-channel.

If i run it like below, its fine:

```
exec("identify -format %r  ".$real_location,$output);
```

However, i would perfer to stay away from exec() and try to stick to the library if possible.

I had a look through my PHP error logs and came across the following:

```
httpd: magick/option.c:1264: GetImageOption: Assertion `image_info != (ImageInfo *) ((void *)0)' failed.
[Mon Mar 26 15:40:26 2012] [notice] child pid 1582 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

Comment: try to catch  `ImagickException` and see whats the probem

Comment: how do i do that? I can't find anything on the web/etc on it. Is there a toggle or setting somewhere in php that does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further investigation and what I was trying to do is check if an image is CMYK. I found that the following code fixed my reason, but doesn't fix the error:

```
$image = new Imagick($real_location);
$ident = $image->getImageColorspace();  
if($ident ==  Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK) {

}
```